# Python print command with variables

Tags: python-3.x, printf

I tried to use `print` function in python 3.4 and when I use:

```
print("abcd %s efgh" % <name of variable>)
```

the value of the variable is shown after `abcd`, and then it breaks the line and shows `efgh` in a new line.

Why?

the full code is:

```
file = open('textfileofipadress.txt','r')
for line in file:
    print (r"net use h: \\%s\c$\utils" % line)
```

the output is:

```
net use h: \\1.1.1.1

\c$\utils
```

break the line....
(the print for the net use is to see what the command output)

Comment: Your variable is probably a string with a line terminator in it, but considering that you posted a syntactically broken code fragment with no context, it's impossible to determine what happened in your actual case.

Answer (score 0):

thanks,
the full code is:

file = open('textfileofipadress.txt','r')
for line in file:
    print (r"net use h: \%s\c$\utils" % line)

the output is:
net use h: \1.1.1.1
\c$\utils

break the line....
(the print for the net use is to see what the command output)